# The code runs on eclipse but hacker earth ide shows Runtime Error

Tags: data-structures, java-8, stack

```
        import java.util.*;
class TestClass {
      public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        while(t>0){
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int pid = sc.nextInt();
        Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<>();
        st.push(pid);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            String s = sc.next();
            if(s.charAt(0)=='P'){
                st.pop();
                st.push(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(2)));
            }
        }
        int a = st.pop();
        System.out.println("Player "+a);
        t--;
    }
  }
}
```

I cannot get the reason why am I getting a runtime error in this hacker earth problem, someone please help!
link to problem:
https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/stacks/basics-of-stacks/practice-problems/algorithm/the-football-fest-6/

Comment: You should format the code in a way matching the structure. Further, don't declare unnecessary `static` variables. Use `for` loops when you have a counting variable. And don't read `System.in` through different objects. Use the `Scanner` consistently. There is no need for an additional `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Thank You for the reply, I have changed the code and then I am using Scanner throughout, this one shows correct output in eclipse but again fails on Hackerearth! Its still showing runtime error.

Comment: You’re handling the `'P'` events, but not the `'B'` events. You only pop once at the end. You should test with different input.

Comment: Hacker earth java editor not user friendly and dont waste time in it.Edior should be friendly like eclipse editor,IntelJi editor.They dont no how to implement freindly editor,simply troubling all candidates

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a java coder myself, but from what I can tell, the problem lies in

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

and

```
int t = sc.nextInt();
```

I think this means that you are looking for inputs in the same line. Hacker earth does not give all inputs in the same line. Most inputs are terminated by new line. The first line input is always the number of test cases (mostly). I think this thing should help.

```
sc.nextLine();
```

Make sure you are providing inputs to your program in the same way in eclipse as it will receive in hacker earth.